# Grails define criteria

Tags: grails, grails-orm, criteria

How can I create(only define) a criteria only once where I have to bind multiple tables under a lot of conditions(so if I understand things right have to use `withCriteria`). And then execute the criteria later two times to get the results.

1. First get the result from a list with offset and max values
2. Get the whole count number

Please help I've tried multiple things but did't get it working...

I was trying something like this

```
def histories = TerminHistory.withCriteria{....} //only define it at this point

def historiesDisplay = histories.list(max: 10, offset: 10) //run it
def historiesCount = histories.count() //run it
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [DetachedCriteria](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#detachedCriteria) for these kind of lazy operations. Sub querying the associations will again be detached.

One form of detachedCriteria is using [where](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/where.html). Look at [wherQueries](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/single.html#whereQueries) which works in the same way as detachedCriteria. Expanding your example:

```
def histories = TerminHistory.where{....} //only defined it at this point
//def histories = new DetachedCriteria(TerminHistory).build{....}

def historiesDisplay = histories.list(max: 10, offset: 10) //run it
def historiesCount = histories.count() //run it
```

*Note:-*
DetachedCriteria and Where queries are available from Grails 2.0 version and above.

Comment: I am forced to use grails 1.3. I solved the problem using totalCount(). Thank you anyway.